# How read and cut off the MSB?

Tags: python, numbers, bit, signed

I have a number that I read from a register on an I2C bus. This is a 16-bit signed number, but Python doesn't recognize the sign bit and uses it as part of the number. How can I read just the MSB of the number and then erase it from the number?

Answer (score 0):

```
value = 0xFFFF
msb = 1 if value | 0x8000 else 0
value &= 0x7FFF

print('msb: {}, value: 0x{:X}'.format(msb, value))  # msb: 1, value: 0x7FFF
```